# Grouping then sorting in template django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have these code in my views.py:

```
array = []
p = Person.objects.filter(client=1,status='Complete').values('name', 'age', 'category').order_by('category')
for x in p:
 d = {'Name': x['name'], 'Age': x['age'], 'Category':x['category']}
 array.append(d)
```

then i got these :

```
[{'Name': u'Mike', 'Age': 20, 'Category':'A'},
{'Name': u'Bell', 'Age': 30, 'Category':'A'},
{'Name': u'Ned', 'Age': 23, 'Category':'B'},
{'Name': u'Ben', 'Age': 21, 'Category':'B'},
{'Name': u'Tom', 'Age': 28, 'Category':'B'},]
```

in my template:

```
{% if persons %}
 {% for p in persons %}
   Category {{p.Category}} :<br>{{p.Name}} <br> {{p.Age}}
 {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I really want to be out-put is like this:

```
Category A:
Mike 20
Bell 30

Category B:
Ned 23
Ben 21
Tom 28
```

do anyone have an idea about my case?
thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup) template tag

```
{% if persons %}
    {% regroup persons by "Category" as people_list %}
    {% for key, val in people_list.items %}
        {{ key|title }} : <br /> {{ val|title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Note that [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) :

> Returns a ValuesQuerySet — a QuerySet subclass that returns dictionaries when used as an iterable, rather than model-instance objects.

so you can remove this:

```
for x in p:
    d = {'Name': x['name'], 'Age': x['age'], 'Category':x['category']}
    array.append(d)
```

and change the regroup to:

```
{% regroup persons by category as people_list %}
```